Getting information about the game using the steam api
How can I get the name, description, price of the game, but not use the `python-steam-api'?
I did so, but it's using the python-steam-api
from decouple import config

KEY = config("STEAM_API_KEY")

steam = Steam(KEY)

game = steam.apps.get_app_details(271590)
print(game)

The Valve documentation only specifies the possibilities to get information about the user, and only through them to take any information about the game
The documentation I was looking at - https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API

You can use steam storefront api. It's separate from the steam web API. It's unofficial and it's used by the steam store itself.
import requests


def get_game_details(app_id):
    url = f"https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids={app_id}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()

    if data[str(app_id)]['success']:
        game_data = data[str(app_id)]['data']
        name = game_data['name']
        description = game_data['short_description']
        if 'price_overview' in game_data:
            price = game_data['price_overview']['final_formatted']
        else:
            price = 'Free' if game_data['is_free'] else 'price not available'
        return {
            'name': name,
            'description': description,
            'price': price
        }
    else:
        return 'details not found'


app_id = 111111  # replace it with our game app id
game_details = get_game_details(app_id)
print(game_details)


Is there an official toolkit for getting information about the steam game?

as fas as I know, no
